# Array contents appear to be disappearing

Tags: reactjs

I am working on developing a game which involves displaying a random assortment of Pokemon cards on the screen using React.

I've run into some difficulties attempting to generate a list of Pokemon due to data being stored in the array apparently disappearing (I'm new to React and so I am sure that I'm missing something).

Within my game component I have the following state defined:

```
const [score, setScore] = useState(0);
const [highScore, setHighScore] = useState(0);
const [level, setLevel] = useState(1);
const [cards, setCards] = useState(4);
const [gameActive, setGameActive] = useState(false);
const [pokemonArray, setPokemonArray] = useState([]);
const [activePokemon, setActivePokemon] = useState([]);
```

My application first generates an array integers which correspond to the type of Pokemon (there are 151) to display:

```
    const generatePokemonArray = (cards) => {

        const generatedPokemonArray = [];
       
        for (let i = 0; i<cards; i++) {
            generatedPokemonArray.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * (150 - 0) + 0));
        }

        setPokemonArray({
            pokemonArray: generatedPokemonArray
        });
    }
```

Following this, it uses the previously generated array to determine the names of the associated Pokemon, and then adds them into another array:

```
    const generateActivePokemon = (pokemonArray, listOfPokemon) => {
        const pokemonNames = [];

        for (let i=0; i<pokemonArray.length; i++) {
            pokemonNames.push(listOfPokemon[pokemonArray[i]].name);
        }

        setActivePokemon({
            activePokemon: pokemonNames
        });
    }
```

The issue I am having relates to the above code block, the for loop is never triggered. If I introduce some console logs the following is outputted:

```
    const generateActivePokemon = (pokemonArray, listOfPokemon) => {
        const pokemonNames = [];

        console.log(pokemonArray);
        console.log(pokemonArray[0]);

        for (let i=0; i<pokemonArray.length; i++) {
            pokemonNames.push(listOfPokemon[pokemonArray[i]].name);
        }

        setActivePokemon({
            activePokemon: pokemonNames
        });
    }
```

[image]

I've been going around in circles for a while now trying to understand what is happening here, but I have had no luck and would be hugely grateful for any suggestions.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are passing a object `pokemonArray` that has a `pokemonArray` key. If you destructure it first you would have extracted the array and it should work:

```
const generateActivePokemon = ({ pokemonArray }, listOfPokemon) => {
    const pokemonNames = [];

    for (let i=0; i<pokemonArray.length; i++) {
        pokemonNames.push(listOfPokemon[pokemonArray[i]].name);
    }

    setActivePokemon({
        activePokemon: pokemonNames
    });
}
```

though the reason you have an object seems to be that you are turning an array state into an object:

```
    setPokemonArray({
        pokemonArray: generatedPokemonArray
    });
```

where it should be like:

```
    setPokemonArray([generatedPokemonArray]);
```

and that it seems the same case to `activePokemon` too. An initial array state turned into an object.

all in all, the correct approach is you should fix your code to work to set your states as array:

```
const generatePokemonArray = (cards) => {

    const generatedPokemonArray = [];
   
    for (let i = 0; i<cards; i++) {
        generatedPokemonArray.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * (150 - 0) + 0));
    }

    // pass an array
    setPokemonArray([generatedPokemonArray]);
}
```

---

```
const generateActivePokemon = (pokemonArray, listOfPokemon) => {
    const pokemonNames = [];

    console.log(pokemonArray);
    console.log(pokemonArray[0]);

    for (let i=0; i<pokemonArray.length; i++) {
        pokemonNames.push(listOfPokemon[pokemonArray[i]].name);
    }

    // pass an array
    setActivePokemon([pokemonNames]);
}
```

Comment: Ahhh I see - I have changed it now and it is working - thank you very much. Really appreciate your help! @buzatto